# "import type" fails for unclear reasons in Typescript

Tags: typescript, import

It looks like this:

```
import type { SomeType } from "./SomeFile";
```

My IDE is totally fine with what I'm doing, but when I run `tsc` it gives me a bunch of errors like:

```
src/Sourcify/SourceProxyArray.ts:6:13 - error TS1005: '=' expected.

6 import type { DeriverScopeProps } from "../Derivations/DeriverScope"
              ~

src/Sourcify/SourceProxyArray.ts:6:40 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

6 import type { DeriverScopeProps } from "../Derivations/DeriverScope"
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

My "target" is `esNext`, and I don't really have anything better than these error messages to go off.

Comment: Your TS version is out of date and doesn't understand type-only imports.

Comment: Or maybe there is more code above that import that is invalid and throws off the parser. Can you show the first 6 lines of this file?

Comment: It was the version.  These features are behind a major upgrade, so `npm i typsecript` alone is not enough to get them.